# How to set app-icons in XCode 5?

Tags: ios, icons, xcode5

I am using XCode 5.

I am properly setting up all app-icons in proper size and resolution.

When I run the app in iPhone Simulator, the app-icon displays correctly. But, when I change the simulator from iPhone to iPad, then the app-icons does not appear.

What could be the root cause of issue ?

Comment: Did you set both sets of icons? You need one set for an iPhone and another set (at different sizes) for the iPad.

Comment: @vijayvala I have posted a checklist for your ease. Kindly go through. You may find a similar checklist on apple's official documentation as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: @VijayVala were you able to find the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Few Tests**

1. Make sure you have set the icons for iPad as well.
2. If you have, you can probably stop the project, quit the simulator manually, clean, build and run the project by selecting iPad Simulator.
3. Make sure you have all the icons set -ie- iPhone and iPad specific. Following is the checklist for the same:

**App Icons**

[image: App Icons Info]

**Splash Screens**

[image: Splash Screens Info]

Hope this helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

Icon size for iphone and ipad differs. Check here for apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/qa/qa1686/_index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Click on project name.On the right side click General Tab and check whether you have added icons of correct resolution or not.

Answer (score 0):

Icons for Universal Apps

Universal applications use the following icons. Items marked with "Required" must be included.

[image]

In addition to the above icons, universal applications with a deployment target of iOS 6.1 or earlier use the following icons. Items marked with "Required" must be included if the application's deployment target is iOS 6.1 or earlier.

[image]

more detail https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/qa/qa1686/_index.html

Comment: I have also found that you have to provide certain naming conventions to the icons as well. Otherwise, it doesn't accepts. It has happened to me a lotta times. I don't know whether it s a bug or not. I, therefore have provided the naming convention as well in my answer which I generally follow. Hope this would be helpful.